# disable-output-escaping twice in a DVWP using XSLT

Tags: xslt, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a custom list. That custom list has a plain text milti-line field. In it the user will enter HTML, like `<br>hi</br>`;

I want to render that HTML in my DVWP using XSLT.

`<xsl:value-of select="@Field_Name" disable-output-escaping="no" />` outputs `&lt;b&gt;hi&lt;/b&gt;`

`<xsl:value-of select="@Field_Name" disable-output-escaping="Yes" />` outputs `<b>hi</b>`

Anyway I can make it render the actual HTML? So I want it to output **hi**.

Comment: "*So I want it to output **b**.*" Shouldn't it be **hi**? And if you don't want to include the markup, how exactly would it become bold?

Comment: @michael.hor257k: woops. fixed. What do you mean not include the mark-up? I want it to render the markup. Right now it escapes the output.

Comment: XSLT can output XML, HTML or plain text. Plain text cannot be bold.

Answer (score 0):

Change your custom field from Plain text to Rich text type because plain text assume  `<b>hi</b>` as part of data. If you change your field type can see html formated text in your browser with same xslt code like **hi**.

Comment: That doesn't work. It renders either `<div>&lt;b&gt;bye&lt;/b&gt;</div>` or `<b>bye</b>` depending on what I set `disable-output-escaping` to.